# macro create excel table to powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am new to using VBA so there is a chance this has been done before but I cant find a discussion on this. I have a template ppt already created that I need tables to be added to specific slides (see image).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pmza.png]

Would it be easier to create a table and run it into Powerpoint? or Connect it with a pre-existing table in PPT that can be populated?

Comment: "See image"... What image?

Comment: @Joel I can see it, can you not?

Comment: You might want to review this [Link](https://www.thinkoutsidetheslide.com/automatic-updating-of-excel-tables-in-powerpoint-slides/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options you have. You can either export the **Excel Range as an OLE Object, a PowerPoint Table Object, or a Linked OLE Object**. Each has its own advantages and disadvantages but, in your case, I would just paste it as a table if the formatting doesn't have to match exactly.

Here is some code that will demonstrate pasting a range of cells to PowerPoint, from Excel, using VBA.

```vb
Sub ExportMultipleRangeToPowerPoint_Method2()

    'Declare PowerPoint Variables
    Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim SldArray as Variant
    
    'Declare Excel Variables
    Dim ExcRng As Range
    Dim RngArray As Variant
    
    'Populate our array. This will define two ranges that exist in Sheet 1.
    'This also populates our slide array which specifies which slide each range is pasted on.
    'YOU WILL NEED TO CHANGE THIS IN ORDER FOR IT TO WORK ON YOURS!
    RngArray = Array(Sheet1.Range("A1:F8"), Sheet1.Range("A10:F18"))
    SldArray = Array(1, 2)

    'Create a new instance of PowerPoint
    Set PPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application
        PPTApp.Visible = True
    
    'Create a new Presentation
    Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add
    
    'Loop through the range array, create a slide for each range, and copy that range on to the slide.
    For x = LBound(RngArray) To UBound(RngArray)
    
        'Set a reference to the range
        Set ExcRng = RngArray(x)
        
        'Copy Range
        ExcRng.Copy
        
        'Enable this line of code if you receive an error about the range not being in the clipboard - This will fix that error by pausing the program for ONE Second.
        'Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
        
        'GRAB AN EXISTING SLIDE.
        Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slide(SldArray(x))
        
        'Paste the range in the slide as a Table (Default).
        PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault
    
    Next x

End Sub
```

Again, it really depends on how frequently you update it but most of the time I push people to keep it easier before making it harder. If you need more a step by step walkthrough, I do have a series on YouTube which you can follow along. It's especially helpful if you want to do more advanced stuff like positioning or even pasting as different data types. Here is the playlist: [Excel to PowerPoint](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcFcktZ0wnNlFcSydYb8bI1AclQ4I38VN)